# C++ code that involves numbers

Tags: c++, math, cout, cin, pow

i need help with this code.
The purpose of the code is to multiply the first number by the second number and the second number to be multiplied by the third number (by power)

so something like this 1*2^3

i have a working code but it isn't giving me my result

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    // Request three numbers from the user
    cout << "Please provide three numbers\n";
    cout << "First Number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Second Number: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Third Number: ";
    cin >> c;

    // Multiply the numbers and display the result
    d = a * b^c; pow(b, c);

    cout << "\n" << a << " * " << b << " ^ " << c << "=" << d << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `b^c` doesn't calculate `pow(b, c)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use pow(b,c) instead of b^c. In c++, ^ is used for the XOR binary operation. if you really want to use the ^ notation, you could code some operator overloading that would call pow in the background but would be abstracted to the ^, but that's additional code.

Answer (score 1):

`^` is not power operator. You need simply `a * pow(b, c)`.

Answer (score 1):

your arithmetic is not correct, you are using an bit-wise operator (**^**)for something that is not related to power

use instead:

```
// Multiply the numbers and display the result
d = a * pow(b, c);
```

so with

> a=2 b=3 c=2

you can do

> 2* 3^2 --> 2*9=18

Answer (score 1):

The code:

`d = a * b^c;`

is incorrect. The ^ operator is an exclusive or (see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/). You should use this instead:

```
d = a * pow( b, c );
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `d = a * b^c; pow(b, c);` with  `d = a * pow(b, c);` , because ^ operator does not mean power in c++.